# Spring saml hits idp on every request

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, saml, spring-saml

I have been integrating my web application developed in spring with spring saml for single sign on. Followed the tutorial on this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle).

Its working as expected. Authenticating user and redirecting to my application. The only issue I'm facing is on all requests, like on clicking tabs in menu bar or even on clicking some internal links, the application calls idp for authenticating user. And because of that ajax-jquery calls in the application are breaking with error :
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'sp_host_name' is therefore not allowed access."

My configuration is same as what is explained in the link mentioned. Please help if someone knows solution to this problem.

Comment: Normally only the first request is authenticated with SAML. Then an auth cookie is set which is used for subsequent requests. Don't know the details for spring though.

Comment: thanks for your response. I do understand that but the problem is with spring-security-3.1.1. Got this from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118623/spring-security-and-nested-filterchainproxy-writing-saml-service-provider followed the solution and upgraded security libraries to 3.1.4 and now my application is working as expected.